# Windows batch file to move each file to a numbered folder and zip all folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have hundreds of files in the directory c:\test and for each file I want to create a consecutively numbered directory starting at 001 with a subfolder proofRead. I then want to zip each folder using infozip (zip.exe) maintaining the folder paths and delete the original folder like this:

**Steps**

file c:\test\proj123.sdlxliff 
move to c:\test\001\proofRead\proj123.sdlxliff
zip folder c:\test\001 to 001.zip maintaining folder structure
delete folder and contents c:\test\001

file c:\test\anotherproj.sdlxliff 
moves to c:\test\002\proofRead\anotherproj.sdlxliff
zip folder c:\test\002 to c:\test\002.zip maintaining folder structure
delete folder and contents c:\test\002 etc.

I found this batch file to use the file name %dpna to rename the folders but I'm not sure how to add an incremental number instead.

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("c:\test\*") do (
    if not "%%~fa"=="%~f0" (
        if not exist "%%~dpna\" md "%%~dpna\proofRead" 
        if     exist "%%~dpna\" move /y "%%~fa" "%%~dpna\proofRead"
    )
)
```

Any help appreciated.

Update: This is the working batch file I used after the helpful hint on how to use counters.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set counter=1
for %%a in ("c:\test\*") do (
set suffix=000!counter!
echo %%a  - Processing file: !suffix:~-3!
    if not "%%~fa"=="%~f0" (
        if not exist "\proofRead" md "proofRead" 
        if     exist "proofRead" move /y "%%~fa" "proofRead" && c:\test\zip\zip.exe -r !suffix:~-3! proofRead && rmdir /s /q proofRead
set /a counter+=1
)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to include an incremental counter in your batch file. This should help you get going on the rest of the batch file:

```
@Echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set counter=1
for %%a in ("*.*") do (
  set suffix=00000!counter!
  echo %%a  - This is counter number: !suffix:~-5!
  set /a counter+=1
)
```

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction and I have edited my question to include the actual solution.